# Angular Modal Dropdown sometimes opening upper direction

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

Working with a Angular js modal with a dropdown menu. The menu list is pretty long. In 70% time the menu arriving in lower direction then its ok. but approx in 30% time the dropdown menu arriving in upper direction, then some parts of my list is going hide. is there any way to make it always in lower direction???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you provide some code? Do you use external modules? Bootstrap maybe? I can only guess it's more like CSS issue. Try this:

```
.dropdown .dropdown-menu {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0px;
}
```

Comment: Yes Damiano you are right. I am using Bootstrap. I am sorry I couldn't describe my problem properly. I am just a trainee, working with Angular js from few a days. Thanks for your answer. I am trying with it.